# I need to find the right age of the applicant using data transforms in pega

Tags: pega

I have a UI with a single page properties from a Data type called "customerinfo", From the selected DOB using a data transform, i need to calculate the age of the applicant. Please tell what are the steps i need to follow in the Datatransform and what functions i will be using to calculate.
Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@DataTime#DateTimeDifference(String strBeginTime,String strEndTime,String strPrecision)
```

Computes the time difference between two DateTime strings; return the difference as double value corresponding to the specified precision

**strBeginTime**: starting time

**strEndTime**: ending time

**strPrecision**: desired precision, one of "CYMDhmsS" to specify
century, year, month, day, hour, minute, second, or millisecond respectively
return double difference to specified precision, -1 if parameters invalid.

Example:

```
DateTimeDifference("20090109T160000.000 GMT", "20090109T162504.370 GMT", "s") = 1504.0
```

For your scenario below should be the template

```
@DateTime.DateTimeDifference(YourDateTimeProperty,@DateTime.CurrentDateTime(), "Y")
```